# How big is the "opening book" of a typical tournament player

Tags: opening, tournament

How many openings does a typical (national/international level) tournament player usually know and play?

For instance: in a tournament, can I expect that a player will either open `1.d4` or `1.e4` consistently when they have white? And, if black plays (for instance) `1...e6`, can I expect their move 2 to be always the same? How long of an opening line will they typically follow without changes (given the opportunity)?

Or maybe they have a single opening that they play 80% of the time, for instance, and then they change completely when they feel like doing something different?

I am not speaking about top-level matches such as a world champion match, where many matches between the same two players are played with a lot of preparation, and I can expect them to vary a bit more.

Comment: about what type of players you ask? there are players(even GM's) who play only one maximum two openings all their life, they now those till perfection; there are players of different type like Vasily Ivanchuk - every GM know there is no reason to prepare against him - he can play anything. This really depends on a players character and dedication to chess and will to explore it, not on the level of player.

Comment: @Drako Thanks, that sounds like an answer! It doesn't surprise me that there are extremes in both directions, but what is the most common approach that is encountered here?

Comment: I really think its very individually - there are no rules definitely, depending on personality you can be successful with any approach and they all will have their pros and cons; so if you play 1 opening all your life at some point your risk to seriously fail in the opening is close to 0, but at same time on serious level your "risk" to get some serious opening advantage is also close to 0, because all opponents are perfectly prepared. But if you try to learn many - even genius like Ivanchuk sometimes fails in opening miserably; because you can't know everything in all of them.

Comment: I believe most players consistently open either with 1.d4 or 1.e4, also because both lead to very different play and normally only one of both styles suits you. The same goes for Black’s first move.

Comment: I like this question. I have wondered the same thing, though to answer authoritatively would want some analysis, would it not? That respectable openings I cannot play should exist has always bothered *me,* but this is a peculiarity of my personality. You are right. Many players specialize and do well by specializing, but how many? I wonder.

Comment: @Drako Of curiosity, what's your repertoire? Or do you too play anything, as Ivanchuk does?

Comment: Yasser Seirawan gave one of those talks, video online somewhere, at the St. Louis Chess Club, about openings he played as a teenager. Not only did he nearly always play the English 1. c4 but, as White, almost always played the same variation of that opening if he could, including b4 when possible. "Here comes Seirawan c4 b4," opponents would say when he entered the tournament hall. Later in life he added some 1. d4 lines but if you read his books for beginners, he talks a lot about *space* and the virtues of *pushing pawns* during the middlegame, which is not usually how a 1. e4 player talks.

Comment: @thb - I'm typically Ivanchuck type player - you don't prepare against me because I quite often decide what to play sitting at the board while my clock already ticking and I can play anything I have played even a4 and h4 as first moves in serious championships :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends.

Myself I play at a 1900 FIDE level and I have practically never studied openings!

Take as an example two players of my club rated 2250 FIDE:

- **Player A: theory enthusiastic**: This player not only have a repertory close to an IM, but he went to a pub before each game to
  study possible development of the games taking in consider what
  openings his rival played.
- **Player B: tactics enthusiastic**: This player do not study more theory and just played for fun at the club. He of course know some
  basis because to reach that level you need to survive against every
  +2000 the first ten moves, but he never prepared any game and uses to fall in second non book lines at the first moves.

Anyhow at a titled level everybody has a repertory. But also at this level there are some masters that know very deep lines of a huge repertory: more than fifty openings with more than ten lines on each one, to make a rude calculation, and others that just do not fall in ambushes, but as player B of my club can fall in non book lines to make think their opponents.

Comment: Since you mention ratings, it would help me to interpret the ratings if you mentioned the scale. 1900 Lichess does not equal 1900 FIDE, for example.

Comment: @thb I am talking about FIDE rating. I thought it was clear because I mention titled players, but I add it to the subject.

Comment: Some casual users mention ratings without qualifying that they speak of online ratings such as Lichess. (Credible estimates vary but have suggested that Lichess ratings might be inflated 350 points or more in comparison to FIDE. Convention on this site is only slowly standardizing on FIDE ratings. One cannot assume. This is why I have asked.)

Comment: The site is unbusy enough that almost anyone can offer advice here, which is pleasant, but what if you have a player like me whose Lichess classical rating is about 1550 (1605 at the moment, but it varies), who has never had a proper OTB rating? Twenty-five years ago, I *seemed* to play FIDE 1350 players about evenly OTB, whereas my Lichess rating today suggests a strength about FIDE 1200; so when I answer questions here (as I occasionally do), how credible are my answers, really? Not very. To rank answers here by OTB ratings would be nice. Probably impractical, but nice.

Comment: But, anyway, there is boasting on the Internet. It's hard to be sure how strong online commenters really are.

Comment: As a point of interest, if you have any online ratings you wish to mention, I would be interested to hear, if only as a data point, as it were. Online ratings do not seem very reliable for any given player, perhaps because some (many?) good players do not take online games seriously; but such ratings still mean something, roughly.

Comment: @thb Anyhow it is neither the same to be a 2250 at Russia than eg at Spain where I live. This effect dissapear at tittled ratings/International players. That's because at Russia you would find lots of well trainned young 2000 players you need to beat. At my country it varies from regions FIDE rating/level too. In fact, player A was rated +2200 but player B was in +2150 (maybe because he didn't like to study a lot theory). I put both as 2250 because my region is a hard one. Anyhow you can simplify it as two excelent players close to reach the lowest international title Fide Master.

Comment: @thb I updated my profile according to your expression. I have not 1900 FIDE but FEDA (spanish federation) because I didn't played a lot of opens when I was on the board, so I putted federated ELO. I agree it is not the same. I am out of boards for two years, but I reached 2200 at lichess on 5 and 10 minutes games. OTB/FIDE 90+30 games I couldn't pass throw 1900 cause I am too much lazy to study opennings and I got crunched by +2000 players on first moves.

Answer (score 2):

It's really less about the lines, and more about the ideas. To become strong, you have to know the typical middle game plans that arise from an opening. Knowing exact sequences of moves is less important, unless a certain sequence confers a concrete benefit (like saving a tempo or preventing counter play).

I wouldn't say that a player's "opening book" is important... it's their knowledge of positions and what plans and ideas to use in these positions that's important. Essentially these are patterns. If you know that a certain position is good for white or black, and what white or black should do in that position, that's a big advantage.